# Transition rate in systems without thermal noise

Tags: noise, stochastic-processes

I've been lately reading about Transition State Theory (TST) and different methods to estimate the transition rates between metastable states in the context of chemical reactions using the review [Reaction-rate theory: fifty years after Kramers](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.62.251) by Haenggi et al. as my primary reference.

The transition between the different metastable states is driven mainly by thermal noise, with the ratio between thermal noise and the energy difference between the states ($\Delta E/k_bT$) being the relevant quantity in a first approximation to determine the transition rate.

I was wondering if these ideas have been extended to systems without a temperature where the noise is not of thermal nature but something else plays the role of $k_bT$. In particular I am interested in systems with a very small number of interacting particles such that the stochasticity associated with the small number of particles can cause the transition between the states. One option would be identifying some kind of effective temperature by defining a noise term but it is not very clear to me how to do this.

I have two ideas of how to achieve something similar: the first would be starting from a master equation perform a system size expansion up to second order and then go from the obtained Fokker-Planck equation to a Langevin description. The second idea is to follow the approach introduced [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9611104) by David Dean and obtain an effective Langevin equation for the density of particles with multiplicative noise from individual Langevin equations with white noise for every particle.

Is there any standard approach to calculate transition rates in this types of systems? Could anyone point me to a reference where I can see how this is done?